# How to call @NamedQueries from interface method definition?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I'm very new in Spring Framework, I want to know if is possible invoke Entity Named Query only defining the Named Query on the interface without any implementation.

I want to do something like this.

```
NamedQuery(name = "StateBo.findByCountry", query = "SELECT state FROM StateBo state WHERE state.country.id = ?")
@Table(name = "STATE")
@Entity(name = "StateBo")
public class StateBo extends BaseNamedBo {

  private static final long serialVersionUID = 3687061742742506831L;

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  @Column(name = "STATE_ID")
  private Long id;

  @Column(name = "ISO_CODE")
  private String isoCode;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name = "COUNTRY_ID")
  private CountryBo country;

  // getters and setters ...
}
```

I defined the Named Query **StateBo.findByBCountry**, my interface looks like this

```
public interface IStateDao extends JpaRepository<StateBo, Long> {

    public List<StateBo> findByCountry(Long id);

}
```

And the interface implementation looks like this.

```
@Transactional
@Repository("stateDao")
public class StateDao implements IStateDao {

}
```

But I have the error that I have to implement the methods that I'm defining on my interface, but I don't want to do that. I only want define my Named Query and define the method in my interface with the same name that is on the Entity and don't add the implementation of that method because the implementation is basically the String Named Query

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spring Data Jpa project.
For start you see https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-jpa/

To execute query without an implementation(only interface) see http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.6.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#jpa.query-methods.at-query

Basically you don't need the implementation:

```
@Transactional
@Repository("stateDao")
public class StateDao implements IStateDao {

}
```

try to remove that and see what will happen.

Comment: What happen with the Autowired annotation?, Because, I'm using the Repository annotation to autowired in other clases? the autowired won't work because there aren't an implementation.

Comment: Spring does the implementation for you. See the guide(first link), there is no implementation there. Spring does it initially.